# True Parallelism in Node.js / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(resolve, ms) })

async function dbQuery() {
  const start = Date.now();
  await sleep(1000);
  const end = Date.now();
  console.log(end - start);
}

async function main() {
  const list = [1, 2, 3];
  const promises = list.map(m => dbQuery(m));
  await Promise.all(promises);
}

main();

Output:

node-space node is-parallel.js
1003
1009
1009
```

I want to dbQuery function to be executed at same time when invoke all 3 promises. Now i'm invoking them and pushing into the array and awaiting them, I believe it is not truly parallel, it like calling each function and pushing it to array in serial fashion.

`sleep` function i have added is just so simulate something async.

Comment: async != parallel. node is primarily single threaded

Comment: also async in javascript is hot/active as soon as you make the call. unlike rust where you have to await the future

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded by design - if you truly want parallel work (and not just awaiting the results of async calls), you might be able to use service workers.

Comment: @DanielA.White Updated the question, can you answer now ?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Updated the question can you answer now. I have seen lot of libraries doing the same type of calculation for timeTaken, then if caller is invoking them in this way is providing wrong timeTaken values.

Comment: The new results will be skewed by `setTimeout` (before getting into any other details), which itself only guarantees a minimum wait time, not an exact wait time.

Comment: So how should we calculate the timeTaken in js then ? @JamesThorpe

Comment: @Sathish Your time calculation is correct. It's your expectation that you will get a ms-accurate sleep which is wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "true parallelism", but it doesn't seem related to the actual question anyway

Comment: Thank you @Bergi . If i want all 3 function to start at the same time, instead of invoking and pushing them into array, what other way i can achieve that ?

Comment: You can't start them all at exactly the same time, because JavaScript is single threaded. Can you explain what it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sathish What does "at the same time" mean to you? Code always executes sequentially. Whether you write `dbQuery(); dbQuery(); dbQuery();` or a loop, and whether you place the results in an array or not, does not matter.

Comment: @Sathish Btw I'd expect that the time difference comes more from the time between the `end` measurements, as between the first and the second time that line executes there is a `console.log` statement which takes quite a bit of time to initialise the stdout stream machinery

Comment: Oh didn't knew that @Bergi .

Answer (score 1):

Async code in Javascript allows interleaving of code execution, but not parallel execution.

Parallelism can be achieved in Node using the [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) built-in module. If you want a web standard solution, you could also user [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).